# How do I do a nullable type constriant?

Tags: c#

Let say I have the following desire, to simplify the IConvertible's to allow me to call them by using a generic type parameter. I plan to do this by creating generic Converter and storing them on a static property of a static generic class. Here is the code to generate the delegates::

```
static class IConvertibleHelper<T> where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    public static readonly Converter<IConvertible, T> Converter;
    public static readonly Converter<IConvertible, T?> NullableConverter;
    static IConvertibleHelper()
    {
        Type type = typeof(T).IsEnum ? Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) : typeof(T);
        Converter = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Converter<IConvertible, T>), typeof(Convert).GetMethod("To" + type.Name,new Type[]{typeof(object)})) as Converter<IConvertible, T>;
        NullableConverter = obj => obj == null ? default(T?) : (T?)Converter(obj);
    }
}
```

As an aside, there was a small side effect of adding supports for Enum's as they inherit from an IConvertible and apparently the conversion from UnderylingType to Enum is implicit and thus only required by the return type of the delegate.

Now, that the hard part is done, I want to add my extension methods:

```
 public static class IConvertibleHelper
 {
   public static T To<T>(this IConvertible convertible) where T:struct,IConvertible
   {
    return IConvertibleHelper<T>.Converter(convertible);
   }
   public static T? To<T?>(this IConvertible convertible) where T : struct, IConvertible
   {
      return IConvertibleHelper<T>.NullableConverter(convertible);
   }
 }
```

The first extension method is fine, and even works! 
The second extension does not compile at all. I can use the following rather lame work around:

```
 public static T? ToNullable<T>(this IConvertible convertible) where T : struct, IConvertible
 {
  return IConvertibleHelper<T>.NullableConverter(convertible);
 }
```

But then we're stuck with requiring to call a different signature to convert to nullable value types. 
An even poorer workaround (for usability reasons,imo), is to use an out or a ref parameter for the return, and right two methods. This technically allows for type inference magic to occur, but makes calling this simple little extension method more annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say you are not allowed to have a nullable type within the angle brackets it just isn't allowed.  I know this is lame, but its how the compile works today.  You couldn't put a concrete nullable type there either, for example "bool?"

This requires you to either change your method name or add some parameters. Sorry I know this is not what you where hopping for but its not easy to get around the compiler itself.  So your ToNullable workaround is as good a solution as any.

Comment: Although `bool?` wouldn't be allowed in angle brackets, the expanded form `Nullable<bool>` would be. So you could have `To<Nullable<T>>`.

Comment: @Bradley You may want test that because Nullable<T> inside of the angle brackets doesn't compile. As far as I can figure you can't nest generic declarations.  The workaround Michael did is the only real work around to his question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ToNullable<T>` workaround is the closest you'll get. Even if there *were* a syntax for what you want, method signatures *aren't allowed* to differ only by generic constraints.